React native, Android dark mode changing icon color
In my react native app i have this icon from import { ArrowBackIcon } from "native-base";
and im using it like this
<Pressable onPress={() => navigationRef.goBack()}>
          <ArrowBackIcon size="lg" color="white" />
        </Pressable> 

the problem is that if i turn dark mode on in my phone the icon turns black the same as the background so it looks invisible


You can first go to this website and read the documentation : https://reactnative.dev/docs/appearance?guide=android

You can use my code as a reference to get dark mode functionality
import { Appearance } from 'react-native';
import { ArrowBackIcon } from 'native-base';

const CustomArrowBackIcon = () => {
   const colorScheme = Appearance.getColorScheme();

   return (
      <ArrowBackIcon size="lg" color={colorScheme === 'dark' ? 'white' : 'black'} 
      />
   );
};



